# Email Reminder Workflow Error 500

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have created a simple email reminder workflow for the owners of the site to know when a document has been added to a doc library.

The workflow is set to start when a new item is created, it starts but within a minute it goes into a suspended status because of the HTTP 500 error.

> RequestorId: bacce1df-95db-31a5-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: **HTTP 500**
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["16"],"SPRequestGuid":["bacce1df-95db-31a5-96a7-436751b2009a"],"request-id":["bacce1df-95db-31a5-96a7-436751b2009a"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4649"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Tue,
>   16 Dec 2014 15:44:09
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly the error is generic. It indicates that something went wrong with your workflow.

Since you are using SPD there is no way to debug your WF. Your best bet is to fire up Fiddler and inspect which request is failing. Then try to map failed request to activity within WF. I had exactly the same error today and I have traced it to web service call using Fiddler.

For debugging options you can look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn508412%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Please look at the following link which provides the solution...
http://summit7systems.com/workflow-2013-starts-and-then-immediately-cancels/

Comment: you should summarize the link so that, if the link ever gets broken, the answer is not lost.